# raytracing for occupancy grid map

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello: Can someone help me to get the ray-tracing code for occupancy grid map. I know its somewhere sitting may be in costmap or gmapping or a standalone node but I want to know exactly.

I am looking for something like:

```
void raycasting_occupancygridmap(robot pose, &range image);
```

This function should take the robot pose as input and return range image as output.

this function have the following information:

```
1. current grid map
2. sensor parameters (FOV, resolution and may be max range if needed)
```

looking forward for help.

Thanks in advance
Daniel

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33058/raytracing-for-occupancy-grid-map/) by [Danielstar](https://answers.ros.org/users/2286/danielstar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-05-01

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2012-05-01**:
This looks an awful lot like you're asking us to do your homework for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have a look at the `costmap_2d` package if you'd like some help. The "costmap_2d.cpp" source file contains most of the raytracing source code used in populating the costmaps with observation data from laser scans and point clouds.

Your problem is very large, and is not something that we can directly help you with. Take a look at costmap_2d, and if you have any specific questions, feel free to ask for help with them, but this question is extremely broad for us to help you.

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2012-05-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [shrini96](https://answers.ros.org/users/104316/shrini96/) on 2023-06-14**:
It's been too long since this answer, but I am also looking for something similar. The implementation of `raytraceLine` in `costmap_2d.h` (for Noetic) accepts starting x, y coordinates and ending x, y coordinates. The point of ray tracing as I understand is to find a range that would eventually give me the ending x, y coordinates (or vice versa). Thoughts?